# Optimizing Test MSE when doing the traning

Tags: probability, statistics

I am reading  "An Introduction to Statistical Learning (ISL)", 2.2.2 The Bias-Variance Trade-Off.
It state that training MSE is different with test MSE. Namely training MSE is

[image]

It refers to the average test MSE that we would obtain if we repeatedly estimated f using a large number of training sets, and tested each at x0.

Now my question is that why don't we optimize the same thing for training MSE. I mean, what happens if for a parametric method (suppose outcome is a linear function of inputs), what happens if we repeatedly calculate the parameters on each sub set of the traning data set, instead of calculating only once on hte whole data set?